# Disable certain keys, but not for textarea and input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preventdefault

I've checked this wonderful websites database and somehow provided answers does not work.

To prevent glitches, by default I must disable arrow keys and spacebar. That works with this code:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

But arrow keys and space bar are necessary for certain areas of website (input and textarea fields). To allow, I did as follows:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) && ($(event.target)[0]!=$("textarea, input")[0])) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

But it does not seem to work. Help much appreciated!

Comment: You just forget a left parenthesis..should be like this `if(([32,`

Comment: so you are comparing the target to only the first input on the page? So that will only be true with the first input/textarea on the page. All others will not be true...

Comment: @robert-rozas thanks for pointing out, but with that set, still the keys are working

Comment: Consider setting a handler for the input and textarea and using `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: @JCOC611 thanks for such a quick response! The second code is put together from two answers found here @ stackoverflow... could you please give example on how it should look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, one option you have is setting an event handler for all the `textarea` and `input` elements and utilizing `event.stopPropagation()` in order to prevent the window event handler from being fired. With this, the elements capture the keydown event and then tell the JavaScript engine not to fire other event handlers of elements that are higher in the DOM chain (such as the document or window).

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

And with jQuery:

```
// Function gets run after document is loaded
$(function(){
   $("textarea, input").keydown(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation()
   })
});
```

Edit: working [jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/8evpLnng/)

Comment: Somehow this solution affects this http://steadicat.github.io/labels/ How's that?
The labels don't vanishes if text is filled in input/textarea.

Comment: The event handler for stopping event propagation is overwriting the one from the plugin. In this case you can either use the method you had in mind initially or edit the plugin slightly to have `.stopPropagation()` somewhere on its own event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the targetted element name using the `nodeName` property:

```
var targettedElement = $(event.target)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase(); // its uppercase by default
```

Then you can use that to check conditionally:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var targettedElement = $(event.target)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if(
        [32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1
        && targettedElement != 'textarea'
        && targettedElement != 'input'
    ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/uwct522v/1/)

Comment: thanks for devoting your time, but 1st answer nailed it!